# Not to mention A and/or B?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

I want to express

> X is prohibited. Of course A is prohibited. Of course B is also prohibited.

Should I use

> X is prohibited. Not to mention A and B.

or

> X is prohibited. Not to mention A or B.

?

(Note: The intended readers of these sentences are computer-scientists.)

Comment: *and*, of course. If the OP is in the computer science area, the OP would certainly know beyond doubt.

Comment: @Kris I wanted to use *or*, because of "You can not do A or B."

Comment: I do not see any confusion myself. I'm not sure why you do.

Comment: *Like A and B, X is prohibited*. (But proofreading help is really off-topic here.)

Answer (score 2):

A vote for

> Not to mention A *or* B.

It is certainly better logically, which computer scientists would appreciate. In formal logic, as in most computer languages,

> not   [mention A   *or*   mention B]
>     =  
>   [not mention A]   and   [not mention B]

[(De Morgan's Law)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Answer (score 1):

**Update** in light of Kris's comment to avoid pseudocode on ELU, the English version of my answer is :

> X, A or B are prohibited.

For an audience of computer-scientists, a snippet of psuedo-code not English sentences seems appropriate.

For reference only, something like

```
Boolean isAllowed := !(X|A|B)
```

Also phrases like 'of course' and 'not to mention' in a technical document may not be appropriate; they risk sounding patronising. I suggest omit those phrases and stick to the facts and formulae.

Comment: You reminded me that I don't have to stick to 'not to mention'. It's not a technical document, though.

Comment: Another suggestion, simply : X, A or B are prohibited.

Comment: I'd have done that if the list has just three elements.

Comment: I'm bit confused as only 3 elements in original question. Regardless, does the general pattern above work for your list ?

Comment: I was specifically asking for a word choice, so difference between 3 and 11 elements was not significant. If 'general pattern' means 'not to use not to mention', then yes.

Comment: k1eran, we are on ELU, not SO ! So this is not an answer.

Comment: @Kris I've updated to include English version. I left the pseudocode but just as a reference, as it is at least a good way to make sure we've understood the questioner's requirement.